# Why does the following batch code may exit?

Tags: batch-file

I am using this batch to automatically restart some program, they are running very well, but sometimes the batch exit, which causes process_1 and process_2 also exit. It seems that everything is normal, but the batch itself crashes. Why ?

```
@echo off

cd %~dp0

set process_1=process_1.exe
set process_2=process_2.exe
set interval=10

:check_service 

tasklist > task_tmp.txt

findstr %process1% task_tmp.txt> NUL
if ErrorLevel 1 (
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL 
    goto start_1
)

findstr %process2% task_tmp.txt> NUL
if ErrorLevel 1 (
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL 
    goto start_2
)


timeout /t %interval% /nobreak > NUL
goto check_service

:start_1

start /b "" %process_1%
echo %date% %time% %process_1%  " down, up it" >>  start_note.txt
goto check_service 

:start_2

start /b ""  %process_2%
echo %date% %time% %process_2%  " down, up it" >>  start_note.txt
goto check_service
```

Comment: Your example shows two non-standard/undefined variables, `%process_printer%` and `%process_ui%`. I also doubt that there's any benefit in using `Start`'s `/B` option and the only file you should be writing is `start_note.txt`. If you open up a Command Prompt window and enter `TaskList /?` you'll be able to read the usage information for that command. Using `GoTo`'s isn't a very efficient way of structuring your batch scripts, and less so when you're repeating code under those labels.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe simplify like this:

```
@echo off
Set "MyProcess1=process_1.exe"
Set "MyProcess2=process_2.exe"

:check
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /i "%MyProcess1%">nul || echo starting %MyProcess1% && start "process 1" "%MyProcess1%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /i "%MyProcess2%">nul || echo starting %MyProcess2% && start "Process 2" "%MyProcess2%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /t 10 /nobreak >nul
goto check
```

Full qualified file names are used for the commands `tasklist`, `find` and `timeout` to make this batch file independent on the values of the **local** environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` and to avoid that the Windows command processor has to search for these three executables.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code like this:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
:chkservice
tasklist | find /I "Process_1.exe" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
  start Process_1.exe  
  echo %date% %time% Process_1.exe Down up, it >>startnote.txt
)
tasklist | find /I "Process_2.exe" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
  start Process_2.exe  
  echo %date% %time% Process_2.exe Down up, it >>startnote.txt
)
timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
goto chkservice
```